# opencart localhost site always redirect to live site url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, opencart, httpserver

I trying to run this site on `localhost/justborngarments` but it always redirecting to live site www.justborngarments.com . How can I solve this problem?

**config.php**

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", "0"); 

error_reporting(0);

// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost/justborngarments/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://localhost/justborngarments/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'D:\xampp\htdocs\Justborngarments/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'D:\xampp\htdocs\Justborngarments/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', 'D:\xampp\htdocs\Justborngarments/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', 'D:\xampp\htdocs\Justborngarments/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', 'D:\xampp\htdocs\Justborngarments/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', 'D:\xampp\htdocs\Justborngarments/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', 'D:\xampp\htdocs\Justborngarments/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', 'D:\xampp\htdocs\Justborngarments/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'D:\xampp\htdocs\Justborngarments/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', 'D:\xampp\htdocs\Justborngarments/system/logs/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'justborn_db');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'jo_');
?>
```

**htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_route_=common/home$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.justborngarments.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Check for Store url from admin panel. Loged in to `admin panel` and click one `System->settings`

Comment: @JitendraYadav : In store url textfield http://www.justborngarments.com/ .

Comment: Then change it to `http://localhost/justborngarments/` :)

Comment: @JitendraYadav : I have changed it. but, still it redirects to live site..

Comment: Try once after removing all the things from `.htaccess` file. Bcz if you updated the `store url` it should work.

Comment: @JitendraYadav : I have removed all things from htaccess and tried. `localhost/justborngarments/admin` is working but `localhost/justborngarments` redirect to live site

Comment: If you are using something like chrome, make sure you clear the cache. Chrome will cache 301 redirects

Comment: @JayGilford : I'm using firefox and I have cleared my cache. But, still it redirects to live site url..

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your .htaccess file contains your live domain name: `http://www.justborngarments.com/`.

Try changing it to your local webserver url: 
`http://localhost/justborngarments`